# What are names of values for outcols param for linkInfo locationattribute in HERE batch geocoder API?

Tags: here-api

I have a project where we have to fetch large amounts of speed limits from lat, lng, bearing values. 
Currently, we are using `HERE multi-reverse geocoder API`, but it turned out that limit of 100 locations in one request is too few for us.

And the question is:

1. Is there any way to include **speedCategory / speedLimit** in `here batch
   geocoder API` (same as
   `Response.Item.Result.Location.LinkInfo.SpeedCategory/SpeedLimit` in
   multi-revers API respones with `locationattributes=linkInfo`)?
2. Or maybe there is some kind of documentation describing how to
       translate here geocoder response to here batch geocoder outcols param values?

Comment: speedCategory / speedLimit is not available in general for the Geocoder API response, you probably would need to use either the Advanced data Sets API or Route Match API

Comment: @JithinKrishnan Thanks, you're right. Route Matching API fits perfect for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinkInfo (incl. speed limits) is not supported by Batch Geocoder. See https://developer.here.com/documentation/batch-geocoder/topics/read-batch-request-output.html for the list of supported output fields.